# Can't instantiate derived MATLAB class without error

Tags: matlab, abstract-class

I get an error whenever I try to instantiate my Pawn class.
"Error using Pawn Cannot define property 'AvailMoves' in class 'Pawn' because the property has already been defined in the superclass 'ChessPiece'."

```
classdef (Abstract) ChessPiece

    properties (Abstract)
        AvailMoves;
        value;
        white;
        position;
        row;
        column;
    end
end

classdef Pawn < ChessPiece

    properties 
         AvailMoves;
         value;
         white;
         position; %position is a 1 by 2 vector with the piece's position on the board
         hasMoved;
         row;
         column;
    end

    methods 
        function obj = Pawn(position,white)
            %UNTITLED3 Construct an instance of this class
            %   Detailed explanation goes here
            obj.hasMoves = false;
            obj.white = white;
            obj.position = position;
            obj.row = position(1);
            obj.column = position(2);
            obj.AvailMoves = {};
            obj.value = 1;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Don’t declare the properties abstract in the base class, then you don’t need to redeclare them in the derived class. I see no purpose to abstract properties.

Comment: Hi LeoSim! Welcome to Stack Overflow. You're doing it right. What version of Matlab are you using, and what OS are you on? Works for me in R2016b and newer on macOS.